# heroku run db:migrate fail as rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dbmigrate

after pushing my latest code Heroku doesn't alter the tables.
when i run "heroku rake db:migrate" i get rake aborted!

its says syntax error but i cant figure where is the error

```
syntax error on line 4, col 586: `      state: ["σלקµ╡╖Θבף","Θ¥עµú«τ£ל","σ▓⌐µיכτ£ל","σ««σƒמτ£ל","τºכτפ░τ£ל","σ▒▒σ╜óτ£ל","τªןσ│╢τ£ל","Φל¿σƒמτ£ל","µáדµ£¿τ£ל","τ╛ñΘª¼τ£ל","σƒ╝τמיτ£ל","σםדΦסיτ£ל","µ¥▒Σ║¼Θד╜","τÑ₧σÑטσ╖¥τ£ל","µצ░µ╜ƒτ£ל","σ»לσ▒▒τ£ל","τƒ│σ╖¥τ£ל","τªןΣ║ץτ£ל","σ▒▒µó¿τ£ל","Θץ╖Θחמτ£ל","σ▓נΘר£τ£ל","Θ¥שσ▓íτ£ל","µה¢τƒÑτ£ל","Σ╕יΘחםτ£ל","µ╗כΦ│אτ£ל","Σ║¼Θד╜σ║£","σñºΘר¬σ║£","σו╡σ║½τ£ל","σÑטΦי»τ£ל","σעלµ¡לσ▒▒τ£ל","Θ│Ñσןצτ£ל","σ│╢µá╣τ£ל","σ▓íσ▒▒τ£ל","σ║דσ│╢τ£ל","σ▒▒σןúτ£ל","σ╛│σ│╢τ£ל","Θªשσ╖¥τ£ל","µה¢σ¬¢τ£ל","Θ½רτƒÑτ£ל","τªןσ▓íτ£ל","Σ╜נΦ│אτ£ל","Θץ╖σ┤מτ£ל","τזךµ£¼τ£ל","σñºσטזτ£ל","σ««σ┤מτ£ל","Θ╣┐σונσ│╢τ£ל","µ▓צτ╕הτ£ל"]'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:146:in `block in load_file'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:145:in `open'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:145:in `load_file'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:172:in `load_yml'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:157:in `load_file'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `block in load_translations'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `load_translations'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:57:in `init_translations'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:71:in `lookup'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:26:in `translate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in translate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb:43:in `catch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb:43:in `block in translate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb:42:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb:42:in `translate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n.rb:156:in `block in translate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n.rb:152:in `catch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.1/lib/i18n.rb:152:in `translate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:102:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:193:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:version => environment
```

**any ideas what is the problem?**

Comment: please explain your comment as im a newbie

Comment: Please find file with that line and show its content.

Comment: there isnt a file with that line and i dont have a db table with that name. i dont know from where the syntax error comes from

Comment: btw, locally it run without errors. the syntax error happends only on heroku production site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into the exact same situation

/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:135:in `load': syntax error on line 4, col 586:

syntax error on line 4, col 586: `      state: ["北海道","青森県","岩手県","宮城県","秋田県","山形県","福島県","茨城県","栃木県","群馬県","埼玉県","千葉県","東京都","神奈川県","新潟県","富山県","石川県","福井県","山梨県","長野県","岐阜県","静岡県","愛知県","三重県","滋賀県","京都府","大阪府","兵庫県","奈良県","和歌山県","鳥取県","島根県","岡山県","広島県","山口県","徳島県","香川県","愛媛県","高知県","福岡県","佐賀県","長崎県","熊本県","大分県","宮崎県","鹿児島県","沖縄県"]'

some of my local /tmp/asset binaries matched the grep statement. I ran "heroku run grep -R "state:" *" and found that the file "vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/faker-1.1.0/lib/locales/ja.yml" matched my problem line. Works fine on my end, but apparently the Faker gem has a problem on Heroku's.

Comment: I found others commenting on Faker problem. I commented out my Faker gem and the app is working again.

Comment: Found another comment... Replaced

gem "faker"

with


gem "faker", '= 1.0.1'

Site works fine.

Comment: I had a similar problem when running a local server using thin. If I used thin start it would give me the error. However, if I used rails server it wouldn't. Any idea as to why?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is if there's a different gem set being used. You had me double-check, I'm using WEBrick on localhost. Heroku I'm using Thin. So, there's a chance the problem isn't wtih Heroku as a platform but Thin?